# Importing Subversion to GIT: problem with subpaths

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

We currently run a big subversion repository, and I'm trying to move it to GIT.  The problem is that it uses trunks and tags below the root directory.  For example:

```
MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\trunk\              <-- master branch
MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\branch\v1           <-- other branch
MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\tags\v1_20100101    <-- release tag
```

There are different departments, OS's, and many different projects.

So when I clone the SVN repository using --stdlayout:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout http://svn-repository/
```

The clone ends up empty.  Without the option, I get a clone, but then branches are treated as directories on the master branch.

1. Is there a way to import this directory structure in one go?
2. If I write a script to import all the Projects separately, is there a way to combine the per-project GIT imports into one big GIT repository?

Comment: `--stdlayout` assumes `trunk`, `tags`, `branch`**`es`**.

Answer (score 3):

If I understande the question correctly, you want:

```
git svn clone 
    --trunk=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\trunk 
    --tags=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\tags 
    --branches=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\branch 
    http://svn-repository/
```

---

Update: you can include more then one --branches and --tags:

```
git svn clone 
    --trunk=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\trunk 
    --tags=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\tags 
    --tags=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project2\tags 
    --tags=OtherDepatment\MyOS\Project1\tags 
    --branches=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project1\branch 
    --branches=MyDepartment\MyOS\Project2\branch 
    --branches=OtherDepartment\MyOS\Project1\branch 
    http://svn-repository/
```

You cannot have more the one trunk evidently.

Git is really designed to support one project per one repository and not multiple projects in one repo. I suppose you will hit many problems trying to use it like that.

Comment: There are many different projects.  I can script the import for each project, but how can I combine them into one git repository?

Comment: Small update about multiple branches and tags parameters. Does this help? Or you want git to automagically guess the complex structure of your repository? I believe it is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to merge multiple git repositories into one?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Git submodules](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial). You'll probably have to import each of your subprojects separately, but the result may mirror your current usage a little better.

Comment: Unfortunately, the book I read ("Version Control with Git") discourages the use of submodules in a rather convincing way